# Can a Spanish citizen live in Denmark and work remotely for a German company?

Tags: germany, taxes, eu-citizens, students, denmark

For context, I am a Spanish citizen currently studying in a university in Denmark (I am doing the full degree there. It is not an Erasmus or any other exchange program.), as part of this studies I am doing an internship in a german company in Germany (that's where I am living right now). Once the internship I will be moving back to Denmark to continue with my studies.

I have been offered a remote working student position (part time) at the company where I am currently doing the internship. The contract that I have been sent states the address that I have now in Germany, but by the time to contract takes effect I will no longer have that address. Because, as I understand, I will have to deregister from my current address once I move back to Denmark after the internship is over.

With that in mind, I would like to know:

1. Is that possible/legal?
2. Where would I have to pay taxes, for this job?
3. Do I need to keep my german insurance?
4. -Can I keep my german bank account (that's where I will get paid)?

Comment: Have you asked the potential employer whether they can handle you as an international remote employee? Even if it is completely legal, their HR and payroll may not support it.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Sweden, the agreement is that someone residing in Sweden but with income from Germany pays taxes in Sweden on that income, but the german taxes is deducted from the ones payable in Sweden.

The rule is that you don't need to pay taxes two times on the same income.

I suggest that you contact the Skattecenter in Köpenhavn.

[http://skat.dk/](https://www.skat.dk/skat.aspx?oid=967&dmy=969&x=971)

Comment: There is also the German side: You pay income tax in Germany if you are a resident in Germany, on your German income (with your world wide income used to determine your tax rate). Since you don’t live in Germany, you pay no tax in Germany, so you pay the full Swedish tax with no German tax to subtract.

Answer (score 1):

As as EU citizen you are granted the right to live and work inside the EU wherever you see fit. So yes, this is legally possible.

However, you need the right paperwork. For taxes, you need to consult a tax accountant locally. For your working contract you need to make sure it's all in order, i.e. the address is correct. As for insurances you need to figure that out with your provider. And it's also more paperwork on the employers end, which they do not have to accept, they could politely decline and reject the offer.

So yes, it's possible. But it's not easy and you will want an experienced professional helping you set this up to make sure no piece of paperwork you mistakenly filled out wrong or not at all will come back years later to haunt you. Helpful posts on the internet will not be good enough for this.

Comment: The employer is trying to keep everything as it is now, with my german address, german bank and so on. I guess to avoid all the additional paperwork that you mention. Would it be an issue to be registered in two addresses in different countries at the same time?

Comment: Possible, but you will need a tax professional for that. Because if you are registered in Germany, Germany wants taxes from the work you perform. If Denmark finds out you are physically in *their* country while you work, using their infrastructure, but pay taxes to Germany instead, they will probably find that to be tax fraud.

Comment: So you need to navigate that and you need a professional, not internet advice. Because most professionals also carry some guarantee that their work is correct. If a professional sets this up and it's wrong, you have to pay to make up for the mistake, but if you did not pay taxes "because the internet said so" then you are in for tax evasion and that's not only paying back the money, that's a crime.